# How to auto scroll (animate) a <div> with text, with overflow set to auto or scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple `<div>` with a lot of text and `overflow:scroll;`

I need the text to automatically start scrolling once it appears on the page but I can't seem to find a straightforward answer. I'm sure there's a javascript solution out there.

I've seen some similar questions but they people asked how to keep the text scrolling while user types in a text field (which is not this case) or how to jump to the bottom of the content when user hovers (which is also not the case)

This is what I have:

```
.textContainer {
  overflow: auto;
  width:260px;
  height:250px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```
<div class="textContainer">
  <p>bunch of text (I would paste Lorem Ipsum here but it's not necessary!</p>
</div>
```

I just don't know what to do next or what are my options to make the text scroll automatically.

Comment: Similar to Onbeforeunload?

Comment: a working snippet of the current state of your script might get you more replies in the next hour

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution:

JS:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('autoScroll'); //YOUR DIV ELEMENT WHICH YOU WANT TO SCROLL
var scroll = 0; //SETTING INITIAL SCROLL TO 0

window.setInterval(function(){ 

 if(elem.scrollTop > scroll)
  scroll = elem.scrollTop;

 elem.scrollTo({ top: scroll, behavior: 'smooth' }) //SCROLL THE ELEMENT TO THE SCROLL VALUE WITH A SMOOTH BEHAVIOR
 scroll += 1; //AUTOINCREMENT SCROLL
}, 50); //THIS WILL RUN IN EVERY 50 MILISECONDS
```

HTML:

```
<div id="autoScroll" class="textContainer">
 <p>bunch of text (I would paste Lorem Ipsum here but it's not necessary!</p>
</div>
```

Change the values in case you want a different presentation

Comment: Thanks Arthur! I tried this but the code is showing me a warning on line 2 that says "Redefinition of scroll", which I'm not sure if it's a thing... It's not stopping me from running the code but it's not working so I'm assuming there's something overlooked there?

Comment: @Satchito Huuum. I'm not sure, but problably when I wrote var scroll = 0 it understood as a boolean. Try declaring it like var scroll; or var scroll = null;. Even with that code it is working for me, it might have something with version.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>This is the beginning </h1>
<button onclick="scroll();">Click Me!</button>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<h1>This is the end</h1>
<script>function scroll() {
  window.scrollTo(0, 200);
}</script>
```

Try this

Comment: Thanks AstroBoy. But is this supposed to scroll my view to the end of the page? My question was more like how to make the text that I have contained in a fixed block automatically start scrolling. Maybe I'm not getting what you're proposing, can you explain?

Comment: So, do want it to go to a div? And also, you can change 200 to whatever number works.

Comment: I gave a <p> tag inside of a <div>, what I want is for the text contained in the <p> tag to animate and scroll inside the <div>. The <div> has a set size in the CSS

Comment: Try using scrollIntoView(); for your p tag? (sorry i cant be of much help)